# after rendering the coloured image of a donut, the render image does't show my donut as coloured,only the icing and plane does

Tags: rendering

[this is the before and after ss of image rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Xrx.jpg)i am using the latest blender 3.6. in blender, after rendering the coloured image of a donut, the render image does't show my donut as coloured,only the icing and plane does, please hlp[image]

Comment: You might have set its visibility off for render. Check the Camera like icon in the outliner. Also what is that grey donut like thing?

Comment: the camera icon is on in the outliner for the donut. also i just moved the "donut" portion away from the icing for easy understanding. i have added the original donut ss now.

Comment: Just check whether the shader node is connected to the output node. If that's connected too, then plz share your file. You can use blend exchange for that.

Comment: can u please explain how do we check that? cant find it on the web

Comment: Just make sure the a line is there between the node named Principled BSDF and Material Output.

Comment: Wait, no, sorry, if that would have been the case, that will just make it go black, It will be this default grey if it has no material applied to it.  To make sure that there is a material applied to it, select the donut go to the material properties and see if the panel is not empty. There should be some material selected. And not a button which says new with a + icon on the left